# How to automatically add identical new polygons to a layer?

Tags: qgis, python, polygon, editing

I am seeking a way, using QGIS, to automatically add polygon features identical to others on the layer. In this case, they are water valves on a water network. Anyone know of a user-friendly way to add new valves that visually line up with the pipes without needing to manually draw the polygons through editor mode?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE, do you have a specific software in mind for this task?

Comment: thanks, artwork. Apologies for omitting that detail--i've now edited my post.

Comment: Is this a spatial task? From your question and the comment below it sounds like a drawing job.

Comment: It's a drawing job with a programmatic approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply start an edit session on the layer, select the feature that you want to re-use and on the Edit menu select Copy then Paste.  This will put an identical feature on top of the selected feature which you may drag and move.

Comment: This is our current solution, but ideally we would be able to automatically rotate the valve to line up with the pipe.

Comment: This technique also copies the attribute data. Ideally, creating the new feature would incite a custom form.